# Split strings in a spark dataframe with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, split, data-science

I'm trying to split strings in a pyspark dataframe column with names and titles separated by different delimiters, in different formats. Eg:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id|                                                                       Text         |                                                                         
|  0| first name last name (title), first name last name (title), and first name (title) |                                                                    |
|  1| title: first name last name title: first name last name                            |                       
|  2| first name last name: title. first name last name: title.                          |
```

How can I get this into a column of just the names?

Desired output

```
| id|          Text         |                                                                         
|  0| first name last name  |                                                                    |
|  1| first name last name  |                       
|  2| first name last name  |
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

`test = table.withColumn('column_new', f.split(f.regexp_replace('column', '[(:;)]', r"$1,"), ","))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your data & code snippets (done it for you this time).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could update your question with a sample of your desired output, because it's not that clear at the moment what you want to put out in the resulting dataframe.